# Apagar arquivo no host do cliente

Tags: php

Bom queria saber, há alguma maneira de deletar um arquivo do computador de um cliente via PHP?

Comment: Não. Isso tornaria muito inseguro acessar sites. Pois qualquer site não confiável ou hackeado, poderia excluir arquivos pessoais do visitante.

Comment: @mauhumor seria muito loco kk paraíso dos hackers

Answer (score 5):

Não existe essa possibilidade, o PHP roda no servidor, então tem acesso a arquivos do servidor e locais do servidor, nunca terá acesso ao locais do cliente, para isso você precisaria de um software desktop, feito em uma linguagem apropriada para isso como Python, C#, C, Java e mais umas centenas..

Comment: Caramba centenas....wow

Comment: Kkk talvez essa parte foi exagerada :p